correlation behaviour when switching some values in one vector to zero
Is there any systematic behaviour in the correlation between 2 variables if we switch some values in the 2nd variable to zero?
here's an example:
# Number of samples
n <- 1000

# Generate correlated continuous variables
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1), 2, 2)
continuous_vars <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = Sigma)

# Binarize the continuous variables
x <- as.numeric(continuous_vars[, 1] > quantile(continuous_vars[, 1], probs = 0.8))
y <- as.numeric(continuous_vars[, 2] > quantile(continuous_vars[, 2], probs = 0.8))
z <- x*y # <- that will turn many 1s into zeros

paste0("sum(x) = ", sum(x) )
paste0("sum(y) = ", sum(y) )
paste0("sum(z) = ", sum(z) )

[1] "sum(x) = 200"
[1] "sum(y) = 200"
[1] "sum(z) = 54"
paste0("cor(x,y) = ", round(cor(x, y), digits = 2))
paste0("cor(x,z) = ", round(cor(x, z), digits = 2))

[1] "cor(x,y) = 0.09"
[1] "cor(x,z) = 0.48"
In this example, the correlation has increased once we switched some 1s to 0s in the 2nd variable.
Are there specific settings in which we would expect the correlation to always be higher when switching some y values to 0?

Why not vary your simulations and see for yourself?

i already have and get an increase which doesn't feel right.  What i'm after is a mathematical proof.

Proofs are not necessary when counterexamples abound!

what i'm after is trying to understand if there's a pattern or certain situations/conditions where it's always higher or lower.

Unfortunately, the question is vague and ambiguous: what specifically do you mean by "some" and by "systematic behavior"?  At present you are basically asking, "if I change my data, does a correlation coefficient change and if so, does the change depend on the original data;" and the answer to that is "obviously yes."

sorry for not being clearer. i'm not asking "does the value of the correlation changes" but in what circumstances would it be systematically lower. I've amended my question accordingly.
